# Compare rows of csv and work out percentage

Tags: python, csv, compare

I'm relatively new to Python. I'm trying to find a way to create a script that looks at a CSV file called "data_old" from a previous month, and compares it with the data in a more recent month called "data_new", then finally outputs that data into a new CSV "data_compare".

The files each month are consistently laid out and look like this (example)

> Month 1
> Company, StaffNumber, NeedToPass, Passed,  %age meeting requirement
> xxxxxxxx, 100, 80, 30, 30%
>
> Month 3
> Company, StaffNumber, NeedToPass, Passed,  %meeting requirement
> xxxxxxxx, 101, 81, 54, 60%

I'm trying to get the output file to compare the data from all rows and show me "Percentage improved, instead of "Percentage meeting requirement". Nothing I try seems to work.

As the numbers change all the time the only common data will be the company name.

I need a simple, explanatory way with comments... as I'd like to understand the logic so I can modify it and add functions.

Much appreciated.

Comment: So all columns except the 1st one (unique company name) contain integer numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Here ist a python code example which might does what you want. This script asumes that the two input csv files have the same amount of lines. In the function `test` the function `zip` i used, which stops if one list is at the end. If your files have a different amount of lines you have to manually loop over both. But I think it is a good starting point

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv


def parse_csv(filename, sort_row=0, as_dict=False, delimiter=","):
    r = list()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # make csv reader object
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delimiter)

        if as_dict:
            # make dict if desired
            header = [h.strip() for h in reader.next()]

        for row in reader:
            if as_dict:
                # make dict if desired
                r.append(dict(zip(header, row)))
            else:
                # strip each item in the row and append it to the return list
                r.append([h.strip() for h in row])

    # sort the list by the first item (company name in this example)
    r.sort(key=lambda x: x[sort_row])
    return r


def write_csv(filename, fieldnames, rows, delimiter=","):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        # make csv writer object
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=delimiter)
        # write the first header line
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)
        for row in rows:
            # write each row
            writer.writerow(row)


def test():
    data_old = parse_csv("m1.csv")
    data_new = parse_csv("m2.csv")
    #write_csv("data_compare.csv", data_old[:1][0], data_old[1:])

    result = list()

    # loop over the items (skipping the first header row)
    for o, n in zip(data_old[1:], data_new[1:]):
        # calculate the improvement (or whatever needs to be calculated)
        value = float(n[4].replace("%", "")) - float(o[4].replace("%", ""))

        # create the row
        result.append([o[0], "%s%%" % value, o[4], n[4]])
        #result.append(["%s%%" % value])

    header = ["Company", "Percentage improved", "old", "new"]
    #header = ["Company", "Percentage improved"]
    write_csv("data_compare.csv", header, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```